# Executing an AutoIt script from Windows Explorer's file context menu

Tags: windows, contextmenu, autoit, explorer

How to make an AutoIt script run as a file verb? For e.g. WinRAR we can right click and compress selected file (or other stuff). How can I make an AutoIt script appear in Windows Explorer's file context menu like that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out these functions:

- [`_ShellFile()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/129955-shellfile-create-an-entry-in-the-shell-contextmenu-when-selecting-an-assigned-filetype-includes-the-program-icon-as-well/)
  <sub>Create an entry in the shell contextmenu when selecting an assigned filetype. Includes the program icon as well.</sub>
- [`_ShellFolder()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/129897-shellfolder-create-an-entry-in-the-shell-contextmenu-when-selecting-a-folder-includes-the-program-icon-as-well/)
  <sub>Create an entry in the shell contextmenu when selecting a folder. Includes the program icon as well.</sub>
- [`_ContextMenu()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/129715-contextmenu-create-an-entry-in-the-desktop-contextmenu-with-the-program-icon-as-well/)
  <sub>Create an entry in the desktop contextmenu, with the program icon as well.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can register your script's `.exe` in context menu to a file type:

1. Open `regedit.exe` and find your file type in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (for example `.rar`). Get the value from there (mine was `7-Zip.rar`).
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<your_value>` and add new subKey with your name (I added `ScriptOpen`).
3. Add subKey `command` with Default parameter as `"<path_to_your_exe> "%1""`.

Here is an example of how to do it from your script (compiled to .exe):

```
RegWrite("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.rar\shell\ScriptOpen")
RegWrite("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.rar\shell\ScriptOpen", "", "REG_SZ", "Open with my script")
RegWrite("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.rar\shell\ScriptOpen\command")
RegWrite("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.rar\shell\ScriptOpen\command", "", "REG_SZ", """" & @AutoItExe & """ ""%1""")
```